# How to bind to SelectedItem property of WPF TreeView?

Tags: mvvm, treeview, inotifypropertychanged, selecteditem, selecteditemchanged

I have adapted the TreeView Control sample project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) for use with Entity Framework objects. It works beautifully, but like many others attempting to update collections or properties on their ParentViewModels based `SelectedItem` changes, I too am unable to bridge the gap of understanding.

I am working in MVVM, and want my code-behind free of any mess. As a beginner, I like the cleanliness of implementing `PropertyChanged` notifications  but since their is no inherent "SelectedItem" property to bind to on the `TreeView`, I am unable to raise my PropertyChanged event as I normally would with `ListBox`.

I too have a SelectedItem property (that actually successfully captures the object where isSelected = true) on my ChildViewModel (see H.B.'s answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7153813/1751090)). I also have a SelectedItem of type ChildViewModel on my ParentViewModel which is bound to my View (see @Martin Liversage's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143193/1751090)). I cannot get them to sync up.

Please help me understand how to communicate the `SelectedItem` property of my ChildViewModel to my ParentViewModel. I do not bind my TreeView to a `CollectionView`, so I am unable to get the `CurrentItem` in the view collection.

My viewmodel collections I'm dealing with are very query-heavy, so I've not included any code for now. Please let me know what is needed for clarity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, at least you're starting to get used to your daily MVVM-WTF... 'Why do I have to post on SO for stuff as basic as this'. One day, you'll love MVVM, I promise ;)

That being said: As you know, the TreeView doesn't support synchronizing the `SelectedItem` property. It does exist, though, but it is readonly. What you want to do, is to extend the behavior of the TreeView to synchronize it's selected item with a property on it's ViewModel.

This problem description points you in the right direction: Behaviors. Behaviors (or, to be precise, System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior<>s) allow you to extend the functionality of any `DependencyObject`. ([Good introduction](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html))

An approach to synchronize your TreeView with a selected item via behaviors, can be found here:

[SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview)

This should do for you already. You can just copy and paste the code of *Steve GreatRex* and go for it. Please comment, if you need help with the approach. Have fun learning!

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry it took so long. Was discerning between this question and an additional understanding problem I was having.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps!