# Unable to bind IsSelected property of TreeViewItem to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Found so many answers in here but none worked for me. here is my XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Helper.View.TreeViewUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:this="clr-namespace:Helper.Model"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Helper.ViewModel"
              DataContext="{DynamicResource TreeNodeViewModel}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:TreeNodeViewModel x:Key="TreeNodeViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding CodeBookEnties}" >
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding DocSetCollection}" DataType="{x:Type this:CodeBookEntity}">
                    <Label Content="{Binding CodeBookName}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding FieldCollection}" DataType="{x:Type this:DocumentEntity}">
                    <Label Content="{Binding DocSetName}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:FieldEntity}">
                    <Label Content="{Binding FieldName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and my viewmodel class goes like this:

```
namespace Helper.ViewModel
{
    public class TreeNodeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<DocumentEntity> children;
        private CodeBookEntity _codeBookEntity;
        private ObservableCollection<CodeBookEntity> codeBookEntities;
        //TreeNodeViewModel _parent = null;
        bool _isExpanded = false;
        bool _isSelected = false;


        public TreeNodeViewModel()
        {
            Mediator.Instance.Register(
                   //Callback delegate, when message is seen
                   (Object o) =>
                   {
                       ParentNode = (CodeBookEntity)o;
                   }, ViewModelMessages.CodeBookCreated);          
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return _codeBookEntity.CodeBookName;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<DocumentEntity> Children
        {
            get { return CodeBookEnties[0].DocSetCollection; }

            set {

                CodeBookEnties[0].DocSetCollection = value;

                //OnPropertyChanged("CodeBookEnties");
            }
        }

        public CodeBookEntity ParentNode 
        {
            get { return _codeBookEntity; }

            set { 
                _codeBookEntity = value;
                if (CodeBookEnties == null)
                {
                    CodeBookEnties = new ObservableCollection<CodeBookEntity>();
                }


                CodeBookEnties.Add(_codeBookEntity);   

                OnPropertyChanged("ParentNode");
            }
        }
        public string Name {
            get { return _codeBookEntity.CodeBookName; }
        }

        public string Description 
        { get { return _codeBookEntity.CodeBookDescription; } }

        #region Presentation Members

        #region IsExpanded

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets/sets whether the TreeViewItem 
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return _isExpanded; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _isExpanded)
                {
                    _isExpanded = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
                }

                // Expand all the way up to the root.
                //if (_isExpanded && _parent != null)
                //    _parent.IsExpanded = true;
            }
        }

        #endregion // IsExpanded

        #region IsSelected

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets/sets whether the TreeViewItem 
        /// associated with this object is selected.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _isSelected)
                {
                    _isSelected = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion // IsSelected

        #region NameContainsText

        public bool NameContainsText(string text)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name))
                return false;

            return this.Name.IndexOf(text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;
        }

        #endregion // NameContainsText

        #endregion // Presentation Members    

        public bool IsLeaf {
            get { return !Children.Any(); }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<CodeBookEntity> CodeBookEnties
        {
            get
            {
                return codeBookEntities;
            }
            set
            {
                if (codeBookEntities == null)
                {
                    codeBookEntities = new ObservableCollection<CodeBookEntity>();
                }
                codeBookEntities = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CodeBookEnties");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used this `usercontrol` in my `mainwindow`. 
Whenever any codebook adds there, i am going to send that information to this `treeviewmodel` via mediator class. 
Based on that it will update its data. Able to add nodes up to 3 levels without any issues.

When i am debugging, selecting any item in `treeview`, the `treeviewitem` is getting bold but `IsSelected` property is not getting hit. I have to get its class based on its selection (CodeBook, Document, Field are the hierarchy of classes here) whenever i select an element so that i can process that element later.
Not sure what is the error. Please help me.

Thanks
Rani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems with your code. Using a `Binding` like this will cause an error because you are looking for the `IsSelected` property in the object that is set as the `DataContext` for the `TreeViewItem` and *not* in the view model:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you *really* want to data bind to the `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` property to your view model, then you could try using a `RelativeSource Binding` instead:

```
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding DataContext.IsSelected, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourView}}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Note that this will search for a property named `IsSelected` in the object that is data bound to the view/`UserControl DataContext` property... I am assuming that that will be your view model. I can't confirm whether this will *actually* work though... enter your next problem.

The `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` property is usually data bound to a property *of the data object that is data bound to the `TreeViewItem`*. Apart from any other reason, this is usually done because a `TreeView` can have many `TreeViewItem`s that are selected and your one property in the view model cannot reference them all. Please see the [Get Selected TreeViewItem Using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143107/get-selected-treeviewitem-using-mvvm) and [WPF MVVM TreeView SelectedItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153813/wpf-mvvm-treeview-selecteditem) questions here on Stack Overflow for more information on data binding like this.

Comment: Thanks Sheridan, It worked for me.I used Viewmodel for each TreeViewItem. Yet to add code for getting the selected item value. (CodeBook, DocSet or Field). Thanks a ton.