How to make TreeView in WPF expandable?
I create a TreeView with TextBlock(for clickable items of treeview) in HierarchicalDataTemplate and data shown correctly, but after any actions with TreeView it collapsing. So is there is a way make TreeView always expandable?
Xaml:
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Fragments, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildFragments}" DataType="{x:Type a:FragmentModel}">
            <TextBlock  Text = "{Binding FragmentName}" ToolTip="{Binding fragmentId}" Tag="{Binding ApplicationViewModel}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="ClickTreeViewEvent"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>                                        
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

Try use TreeViewItem instead of TextBlock, in this case item will be not clickable and can not click on item. Try wrap TextBlock with TreeViewItem, and in thus case names of items will dissappearing and expand element will duplicating.

use  TreeViewItem in the HierarchicalDataTemplate and in the vm item\node have a property bound to the is expanded of the treeviewitem edit: there is an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143107/get-selected-treeviewitem-using-mvvm

Thank you very much for this link. It was helpful for solving issue.
