# Use SelectedItem in a WPF Treeview

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, selecteditem

How can i use the SelectedItem in a treeview? I want to bind i to my Model. Why is this property in the treeview readonly? Is there a xaml Solution without Code-behind?

Comment: Refer to the link here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153813/wpf-mvvm-treeview-selecteditem