# Single Left Mouse Click on TreeView Node to open a document on a different User Control

Tags: wpf, click, treeview, wpf-controls

I have Tree View whose information are filled with a structure of a document.
Every single article is represented by a single TreeView Node.

The goal is to raise the click event, pass the key that identifies that precise part of the document and render the information

I have 3 problems:

1) How can I pass the information to a different User Control
2) The Double click event works (just tried with a simple textbox) but not the single left click... :(
3) How can I open the precise part of the document I select on the treeview and repeat the operation. So e.g.: I click on the article number 3, I want the document of article 3 rendered, I click on article 5 etc. etc.

Code below:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="UserControls.DocumentViewLaw"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="800"  d:DesignWidth="900"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Client.UserControls">
     <Grid x:Name="grdTop">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <TreeView x:Name="treeViewStructure" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" >
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <Border x:Name="bdrTreeViewItem" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0.5" Padding="1">
                            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Text}" x:Name="treeViewItem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                            </TreeViewItem>
                        </Border>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                   <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="OnTreeNodeMouseClick" />
                            </Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightBlue" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
                                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="9" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Resources>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger SourceName="treeViewItem" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="bdrTreeViewItem" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                                <Setter TargetName="treeViewItem" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <controls:TabDocumentViewLawControl x:Name="topTabLaw" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

CodeBehind:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Client.UserControls
{

    public partial class DocumentViewLaw : UserControl
    {
        public DocumentViewLaw()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SetTreeViewNodeStructure(IList<TreeViewNode> nodes)
        {
         //this method is recalled in MainWindow.cs where I pass the object returned by 
         // WCF and attached to the TreeView
            this.treeViewStructure.ItemsSource = nodes;
        }

        public void OnTreeNodeMouseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Second User Control where to visualize the document:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Client.UserControls.TabDocumentViewLawControl"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                 xmlns:editor="clr-namespace:RichEditor;assembly=RichEditor"
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="500"
                 xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Domain.Model.Document;assembly=Domain">
      <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
      </UserControl.Resources>
      <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" MaxHeight="250">
        <StackPanel>
          <FlowDocumentReader x:Name="articoloDocumentLaw"  Grid.Row="1" Document="{Binding Path=FlowDocumentArticle}"
                           Visibility="{Binding Path=HasArticoloVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

The object that I pass to the UserControl to visualize the document and his structure in 
"DocumentViewLaw" User Control is the single result of a result list
In MainWindow component I associate the data and correspondant context.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        this.login.btnLogin.Click += btnLogin_Click;
        this.tabMainControl.resultListControl.RowSelected += resultListControl_RowSelected;
    }

    void resultListControl_RowSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutonomySearchResult selectedDocument = (AutonomySearchResult)this.tabMainControl.resultListControl.grdResult.SelectedItem;
        this.tabMainControl.topTabControl.SelectedItem = this.tabMainControl.tabResultList;
        Services.ServicesClient client = new Services.ServicesClient();
        var document = client.GetDocument(selectedDocument.DocKey, true);

        this.tabMainControl.topTabControl.SelectedItem = this.tabMainControl.tabDocumentView;
        this.tabMainControl.tabDocumentView.DataContext = document;

        TreeViewFactory treeFactory = new TreeViewFactory();
        var documentStructure= treeFactory.GetStructure(document.DocumentKey, document.XmlStructure, true);
        this.tabMainControl.documentViewLaw.SetTreeViewNodeStructure(documentStructure);
    }

    public virtual void onResultClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Factory of TreeView:

public class TreeViewFactory
        {
            public IList GetStructure(DocumentKey docKey, string structure, bool loadAllParents)
            {
                //business logic with LINQ2XML
        }

```
    public class TreeViewNode
    {
        public TreeViewNode() { }

        public DocumentKey DocKey { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public IList<TreeViewNode> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank u very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

**1) How can I pass the information to a different User Control?**

I assume that the articles data in the `TreeView.ItemSource` and the data in the second `UserControl` are bound from properties in a view model or class that is set as the `DataContext` of your `Window` or `UserControl`. From your view model, you can either bind to the `SelectedItem` property of the `TreeView`, or monitor the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to see when the property that is bound to the `TreeView.ItemsSource` is changed (by the user). At this point, you can load the required data and update whichever property is data bound to the second `UserControl`.

**2) The Double click event works (just tried with a simple textbox) but not the single left click... :(**

If you data bind as suggested above, then you will not need a `Click` handler, as you can find out when the user selects another node directly in the view model.

**3) How can I open the precise part of the document I select on the treeview and repeat the operation. So e.g.: I click on the article number 3, I want the document of article 3 rendered, I click on article 5 etc. etc.**

I don't really understand this part of your question. You should be able to access all of the properties of the selected item in the `TreeView` when binding to the view model.

Comment: Uhm, I tried adding the SelectedItem property on TreeView but didn't work really...event wasn't able to be reaised.

Comment: Sorry misclicked...

Uhm, I tried adding the SelectedItem property on TreeView but didn't work really...event wasn't able to be raised.

The problem as u can see, is that I don't use datacontext on that user control.
documentStructure is a property of document.
Through the TreeViewFactory I fill the object properties and pass it to the DocumentViewLaw user control.
In the XAML file I use the object as ItemsSource...

Comment: You bind to the `TreeView.SelectedItem` property in the same way and place that you bind to the `TreeView.ItemsSource` property. Then, whenever a different node is selected in the `TreeView`, you should be able to see the property change in your view model. However, if you are not using MVVM with views and view models, and you are creating `DependencyProperty` properties to bind to in your code behind, then you will need to attach a `PropertyChangeCallbackHandler` to the `DependencyProperty` to be notified when its value changes.

Comment: Ahhh... in that case, I'm not sure that I can be of any help. Sorry.

Comment: I modified the TreeViewItem XAML this way:

                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.Selected" Handler="treeViewItem_Selected" />
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

Dunno if it's correct, 'cause if I click for a example a child node that is child of another child node, the debugger goes 3 times in that item handler..O_o

I don't use DependencyProperty :| Can u please make a simple example?
Thank u very much for your help and time

Comment: The `Selected` event will fire each time a node is selected, so each parent node (of the child node that you clicked) will be momentarily selected before the child becomes selected. Binding to the `SelectedItem` property will just give you the child node that you selected directly. I don't really have time for example, but look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153813/wpf-mvvm-treeview-selecteditem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview. Bear in mind you only need read only ({Binding SelectedItem, Elementname=TreeView, Mode=OneWay}). Good luck.